# Can a Software Engineer become a CNC programmer?

Tags: job-search, graduate

I just graduated with a Bachelor's Degree in Software Engineering. I have a difficult time choosing what field I'm going to be in. I saw a job for a CNC programmer in the area where I live. I have never heard about CNC programming before.

Do you think I can learn this field though the job? Any starting-career advice in software engineering for a 6-months out now graduate?

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that salaries for experienced CNC programmers will typically be (*much*) lower than for Software Engineers.

Comment: I would be wary.  If you are very good working with metals and tools it might work out.

Comment: Do you know what a CNC programmer is?

Answer (score 11):

I mean... There's no laws against it.

There is some degree of crossover in terms of thinking through the logical steps and writing code.

The issue you may find is that there is a lot of practical/institutional knowledge that a company would expect a CNC Programmer to know, that unless you've got hobby experience with Machining/CNC - you will lack.

For example - what is an appropriate Spindle speed, feed rate, Depth of cut for a given Aluminium vs Steel? Different types of steel?

This is not to say don't try and don't apply - Go for gold! You miss 100% of the shots you never take. I'm just saying that if you are serious about it, you might want to start educating yourself about some of the intricacies and nuances of metalworking.

Answer (score 8):

It's a different skill.

Programming a CNC machine involves virtually no conditionals or calculations at runtime. All the detailed decisions about exact feeds, speeds, and tool paths have to be made in advance, with an awareness of the limitations of the tool and the materials. If you've "programmed" a 3D printer, especially down at the G-code level, that's very similar in concept though much simpler.

The ability to logically think through a sequence of operations to their cumulative result transfers over. The rest, not so much.

Basically, you would have a bit of a head start in learning CNC programming... but probably less than someone with a bit of machine shop experience would. If someone is looking for experience in this, you really don't have it. If it interests you, you could certainly learn, but right now you're still at the "hello world" level.

(Typo fixed, with apologies to the CBC.)

Answer (score 6):

You can apply for entry level CNC programming jobs. The worst they can say is no. But your skillset is not really what is normal for that industry. An engineering background or focus is more suitable. So a lot of what you spent time learning will not be used or upgraded in such a position.

Having said that, it's a pretty open field at entry level, no real qualifications are needed at all in my opinion. CNC programming is not difficult to learn at basic level and many people who are experts now started with nothing but an interest in CNC.